# Custom serializing action with DjangoRestFramework

Tags: python, django, serialization

I am having some problem with djangorestframework's serializers.
Below is part of my code.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Image(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='')

class Album(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='')

class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.id')
    album = serializers.Field(source='album.id')
    uploadDevice = serializers.Field(source='uploadDevice.id')

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('id', 'owner', 'album', 'name')

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.id')

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('id', 'owner', 'name')
```

So the thing is, I want to hide the integer id value of the models when they are serialized into json. For example, Image model instance with values

- id = 12
- owner = 425
- album = 24
- name = DSC2091.JPG

will turn into

```
{
    id: '7VHXHIGMH4XWAKYMPSYYYENYA7NPZ7RGVY6GQJMG3BSIQXWZELNQ====',
    owner: 'J2M5BVZB2RCJQNXPN33G2LTMFSAXWPFVFHFTNQSHP56QO3OHFCNA====',
    album: 'HCMOMOEEA7YZEI5JJTTXN7LQHOEW3FCRQ7OB6ZMD7UEWISUG7PFA====',
    name: 'DSC2091.JPG'
}
```

And same in the other way.
I've already made the encrypting, decrypting, and the hashing part.
Where and what should I do to make this id security conversion happen smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout transform methods on serialization: transform_ http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializing-objects

Also validate method does the reverse so you can do the encryption going each way.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is what I am looking for.
I added transform_owner(), validate_owner() method to my serializer class. It works when serializing but validate_owner() method won't be called when I call is_valid() method. 
And this error is thrown
'owner': [u'Incorrect type.  Expected pk value, received str.']